# ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am getting the following exceptions for some Android Devices which is not reproducible, can someone please explain me the reason for the same. The **TargetSDKVerson is 24**, **compileSDKVersion is 24**, **minSDKVersion is 15** and **build tool version is 23.0.3**

```html
Exception:

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abc.activities/com.abc.activities.activities.SplashActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(Unknown Source)
       at com.hdfcclife.activities.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
       at com.lody.virtual.client.hook.c.b.callActivityOnCreate(Unknown Source)
       at com.lody.virtual.client.hook.c.a.callActivityOnCreate(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

```html
Activity Layout:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="all">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_large"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

```html
ext {
    // dependencies versions
    supportLibraryVersion = '24.2.1'
    playServicesVersion = '9.6.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile project(':wibmoSDK')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    //Testing-only
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    // add this for intent mocking support
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2'
    // add this for webview testing support
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.3') {
        // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since the test runner
        // hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    compile files('libs/LiveChatWindow.jar')
    compile files('libs/adobeMobileLibrary-4.13.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao-encryption:2.2.2'
    compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.4@aar'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    compile 'com.anupcowkur:reservoir:2.1'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:percent:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:customtabs:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.shamanland:fonticon:0.1.9'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.6.0@aar' //Apps Flyer
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.1'

    compile project(':PayU-release')
}
```

```html
Adding Activity onCreate Code:

@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT )
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

        database(); // For Database

        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this))
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this);

        Utilities.initCache(this);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            callApi();
        } else {
            moveToNext();
        }

    }
```

```html
  Android Manifest:       
  
        <activity
            android:name="com.hdfcclife.activities.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="hdfclife"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Styles.xml:

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/green_icon_color</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: try to update your SDK then clean then rebuild the project

Comment: do you use 2 different versions of support lib?

Comment: @VladMatvienko no only 1 version is used for all the support libraries.

Comment: can u paste your activity code..

Comment: @Androidjack added activity onCreate Code.

Comment: u must be adding some fragment to relativelayout right?

Comment: @Androidjack No, actually there are a few API calls only int hat activity, so we are not adding any fragments in that, the splash screen image is added through styles as windowBackground.

Comment: can u paste that code

Comment: @Androidjack added the manifest and styles code...

Comment: try updating your build tool version to 24.0.0 and then clean build project

Comment: I am receiving this same error under similar circumstances. Did you find a solution?